# Reading text files paths with the same order of them in the directory in Python

Tags: python, file

```
directory = r'/home/bugramatik/Desktop/Folder'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file = open('/home/bugramatik/Desktop/Folder'+filename,'r')
    print(BinaryToString(file.read().replace(" ","")))
```

I want to read all files inside of the a folder same order with folder structure.

For example my folder is like
a
b
c
d

But when I run the program at above it shows like
c
a
d
b

How can I read it like a,b,c,d?

Answer (score 1):

The order in `os.listdir()` is actually more correct. But if you want to open the files in alphabetical order, like `ls` displays them, just reimplement the sorting it does.

```py
for filename in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, filename) ,'r') as file:
        print(BinaryToString(file.read().replace(" ","")))
```

Notice the addition of `sorted()` and also the use of `os.path.join()` to produce an actually correct OS-independent file name for `open()`, and the use of a `with` context manager to fix the bug where you forgot to `close` the files you opened. (You can leave a few open just fine, but the program will crash with an exception when you have more files because the OS limits how many open files you can have.)